# Windows Azure Active Directory Single Sign On - Custom error page for log in errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, active-directory, single-sign-on, azure-active-directory

We have successfully set up a Windows Azure AD Tenant and implemented web single sign-on in our ASP.NET application in accordance with this tutorial http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn151790.aspx

We are using Organizational Identities for authentication, but if a user is already logged in to another website using a different Microsoft Account (Windows Live ID) we get a very user-unfriendly error message. - "ACS20016: The domain of the logged in user does not match any allowed domain of this STS."

Is there any way we can provide a more user friendly error message? Is there anything like the Error URL in ACS to redirect users to a custom error page if an error occurs during the log in process?

Answer (score 0):

Totally possible.

ACS gives you error messages in encodeed JSON 
like this

```
{"context":null,"httpReturnCode":401,"identityProvider":"Google","timeStamp":"2010-12-17 21:01:36Z","traceId":"16bba464-03b9-48c6-a248-9d16747b1515","errors":[{"errorCode":"ACS30000","errorMessage":"There was an error processing an OpenID sign-in response."},{"errorCode":"ACS50019","errorMessage":"Sign-in was canceled by the user."}]}
```

1. First you need to enable the "Error URL feature" in management portal, for your ACS namespace-> Edit Relying party-> Error URL.
2. You need a helper classes to decode the JSON. [steps here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg185925.aspx)
3. Configure anon access to them Error page.

With this you are in full control of the page, you can show the error message the way want and brand the page to match the look and feel of your relying party web.

Comment: Thanks for you response. However, we are not using ACS and do not have an ACS namespace configured. We are using WAAD to administer our user identities and there does not appear to be an Error URL when configuring Applications under AD in the Azure Portal.

Comment: ACS is part of WAAD  now. You are using Windows Azure Active Directory  Access Control. Same thing

Comment: Do you know how to configure the relaying party Error URL when there is no ACS namespace? We are actually using our existing directory from our Office 365 subscription as described here http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/03/04/managing-windows-azure-ad-from-the-windows-azure-portal-1-sign-up-with-an-organizational-account/